# How can I go back to the previous view from root view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void)cancel {
// What should I do here?
}

// root view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [cancelButton release];     
}
```

I added cancel button in the navigation bar.
I want to go back to the previous view from root view when cancel button is pressed.
What do I have to do in cancel? I added root view controller like this.

```
RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
self.naviController = aNavigationController;
[aNavigationController release];
[rootController release];
[self.view addSubview:[naviController view]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pop the view.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can dismiss it as well.

```
dismissModalViewcontrollerAnimated
```

**EDIT:**
If you are adding the view then you need to remove your view.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: I tried both. When I pressed cancel button, there was no change.

Comment: [self.view removeFromSuperview]; works. But navigation bar still remains and there is no animation when it disappers.;

Comment: You can push your view and then when you pop that view it'll disappear with the animation. Check out once.

Comment: [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview]; removes navigation bar also but without animation. There seems no easy way to push and pop ROOT view controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a navigationController to push the view you can make use of `popViewController: animated:` method. If you presented the view as a modal view you can make use of `dismissModalViewcontrollerAnimated:` method

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not pushing or presenting the `aNavigationController`. You are just adding it as a `subview`. Neither `popViewControlle`r nor `dismissModalViewController` won't work here. You have to just remove it from its superView.  Try this.

```
- (void)cancel {

    [self.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: How can it make work by popViewController? Can you push root view controller instead of adding it like this?   [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController  animated:YES];

Comment: Yes. You can very well do it like that. But, make sure that main view controller is inside a navigation controller.

Comment: I still don't know how to push root view controller instead of adding.  what is wrong with this code? RootController  *rootController = [[RootController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];
[rootController release];

Comment: What do you mean "main view controller is insdie a navigation controller"? Can you show me code about pushing root view controller?  This is what I did. RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];
[rootController release];

Answer (score 0):

Add This.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview]
```