# How do I push root view controller?

Tags: iphone

I want to push root view controller. Why doesn't this code work?

```
RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];
[rootController release];
```

I used addSubview like this before.

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad { // this is root view controller
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [cancelButton release];     
}

RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
self.naviController = aNavigationController;
[aNavigationController release];
[rootController release];
[self.view addSubview:[naviController view]];
```

And I added cancel button in navigation bar to go back to previous view. It doesn't work.
So, I want to push instead of add.

Comment: We need more context. What happens? What do expect? What else are you doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909619/how-can-i-go-back-to-the-previous-view-from-root-view This is the link I asked question.

Comment: What code are you using to go back to the previous view? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Nothing happens? Crashes? Device starts smoking?

Comment: I edited question. I know popViewController doesn't work(nothing happens) because I addded root view controller. So, I want to change to push instead of add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the root controller in a UINavigationController using the

```
initWithRootViewController:
```

method. So, the way you are doing is correct. I would suggest you to inspect `self.view` and ensure that it is not `nil`.

EDIT: after your comment

You need to define a root view controller for your UINavigationController to work properly; from the [UINavigationController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Every navigation stack must have at least one view controller to act as the root.

So you cannot remove the root view controller. Possibly, to make things work as you like you should create an additional view controller to use as root view controller that you do not alter, then push your RootViewController on the navigation stack, then popping would work:

```
UIViewController *baseController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:baseController];
self.naviController = aNavigationController;
[aNavigationController release];
[baseController release];
[self.view addSubview:[naviController view]];

RootController *rootController = [[RootController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];               
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootController animated:YES];
[rootController release];
```

Notice that I first defined a simple UIViewController as root view controller, then pushed your controller on to it.

Once you do this, if you add the cancel button like you do, it will work popping the rootViewController from the navigation stack.

AFTER LAST COMMENT:

If I understand you right, when clicking on the cancel button, you want to get rid of the UINavigationController altogether.

In this case, use the following code for `cancel`:

```
- (void)cancel {
   [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

If this guess is right, keep in mind that since you are not keeping any reference to the navigation controller, it will be deallocated and with it all the view controllers you instantiated.

If instead of removing the UINavigationController altogether, you would simpy hide the navigation bar, then after popping rootController, call:

```
setNavigationBarHidden:animated
```

Comment: Second part of code is what I did before. It worked fine. What I want to do is changing that code to push because cancel button does not work.

Comment: Do I have to do initWithRooViewController before I do pushViewController?

Comment: The problem is that I don't even push root view controller. Poping it is next problem.

Comment: I tried your code. I can push root view controller. But after I pressed cancel button, it goes to the previous view. But navigation bar still remains.

Comment: You can use -setNavigationBarHidden:animated: to hide (or show) the nav bar.

Comment: setNavigationBarHidden:animated doesn't work. [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview] works without animation. Thank you.